# Fixed column header but scrollable data in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

Can we freeze headers in jqgrid?? that is when number of rows exceeds the page size and we need to scroll grid to view data. I want headers to be fixed while scrolling so that user knows the column name of the corresponding column.
Googled a lot about it but couldn't find appropriate solution for jqgrid.

Answer (score 1):

Add below statement

```
$('#' + yourGridName).closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").css({"overflow-y" : "scroll"});
```

after the grid is built.

Comment: Solved my problem by giving the "height:600" attribute. Previously I have mentioned height as '100%' but it seems that if we give value like that scrollbar will disappear from the grid. so by changing the value from '100%' to 600 scrollbar appear back on the grid and then only grid content will scroll instead of the whole grid. Headers will be freezed automatically. No seprate scripting required. :)